# Why does the is_(a,b) function work faster than eq(a,b) in python 2.7.3?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I search the answer why `a is None` works faster than `a == None`. I measure time by using this code:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("1 is None", number=10000000)
0.4035069934390217
>>> timeit.timeit("1 == None", number=10000000)
0.8190256083633187
```

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) says that `a is b` has function equialent `is_(a, b)` and that `a == b` has function equivalent `eq(a, b)`. So, why is the `is_` function faster than `eq`?

I read in some articles that `is_()` compares only the identifiers of objects, and `eq()` does "deep comparison". But I can't find this info in documentation. Does this information correct? Where I can read more about this?

Comment: `So, the question turns into "Why eq() function works faster than is_() in python 2.7.3?".` Why not make that the title?

Comment: Right, this is question is more general. Done.

Comment: You had `is_` and `eq` backwards in your title; I just fixed it. :)

Comment: Also, just FYI: the documentation you link to is to the special `operator` library, which provides functions that do the same thing as the syntactic constructions `is` and `==` (and most others). That _doesn't_ mean that when you write `a is None` it's actually calling `operator.is_(a, None)`; it's closer to the reverse.

Comment: @Dougal thx! didn't know that before.

Answer (score 9):

Testing for identity (`is`) is as simple pointer comparison (are the two values the same object).

Testing for equality needs to do more work than that; for lists for example it does need to test for equality of each and every element in both lists until either something tests negative for equality or all elements in the shortest list have been tested.

Note that the two operators are *quite* different in what they test:

```
>>> lsta = []
>>> lstb = lsta
>>> lsta is listb
True
>>> lstc = []
>>> lsta is listc
False
>>> lsta == listc
True
```

Just because two objects are equal does not mean that they are the same object; `is` tests for the latter.

Comment: Thx for the good answer! But what about comparison with None? This also needs deep compare (when using `eq(a,b)`)?

Comment: For comparison with `None`: `a is None` just needs to check if the pointer to `a` is the pointer to [the special singleton `None` object](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html). `a == None` needs to call `a.__eq__(None)`, which adds the overhead of a method call. Note that it's possible to create an object where `a == None`, but not possible to make one where `a is None`.

Comment: @dizpers: Yes, `eq(a, b)` is implemented as `a.__eq__(b)` and that's method call. More overhead than a pointer comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Python source code implementing comparisons (`is`, `==`, `<=`, etc.):

[Python/ceval.c:4501](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e6cc582cafce/Python/ceval.c#l4501)

```
static PyObject *
cmp_outcome(int op, register PyObject *v, register PyObject *w)
{
    int res = 0;
    switch (op) {
    case PyCmp_IS:
        res = (v == w);
        break;
    ...
    default:
        return PyObject_RichCompare(v, w, op);
```

`is` is implemented in just one line of code, a simple C pointer comparison. Some Python primitives compare equal according to this (because of interning, or because they are singletons like `True`, `False` and `None`).

On the other hand, `eq` uses `PyObject_RichCompare`, which is implemented with the helper function [`do_richcompare`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e6cc582cafce/Objects/object.c#l539):

```
richcmpfunc f;
PyObject *res;
int checked_reverse_op = 0;

if (v->ob_type != w->ob_type &&
    PyType_IsSubtype(w->ob_type, v->ob_type) &&
    (f = w->ob_type->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
    checked_reverse_op = 1;
    res = (*f)(w, v, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
    if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
        return res;
    Py_DECREF(res);
}
if ((f = v->ob_type->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
    res = (*f)(v, w, op);
    if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
        return res;
    Py_DECREF(res);
}
if (!checked_reverse_op && (f = w->ob_type->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
    res = (*f)(w, v, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
    if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
        return res;
    Py_DECREF(res);
}
```

This checks the argument types and potentially tries multiple comparison functions (`__eq__` methods) before it can determine the answer. The comparison methods might do unlimited work (e.g. `list.__eq__` has to check each element of the lists, possibly recursively), but even in the simple case of `x == None`, the type checks and all the extra work will amount to a real slowdown compared to `is`.

Comment: thx! this is the explanation that I need (refer to Python's source code). I didn't know where to search comparison function.